# iOS: UISearchBar appears tinted

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, ios10, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have the following settings for the UISearchBar:

```
            searchBar?.tintColor = UIColor.clear
            searchBar?.barTintColor = UIColor.clear
            searchBar?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            searchBar?.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
            searchBar?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
            searchBar?.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
            searchBar?.backgroundImage = UIImage()
```

And this is how the `UISearchBar` appears:

[image]

Activated:

[image]

I am not sure where I am getting the gray in the background.  I have inherited a codebase that's using `UIAppearence` `Proxy`, but I don't see anything for `UISearchBar`.  Perhaps, the `searchBar` is inheriting it from elsewhere.

Any ideas on how to get rid of the the gray color?

Answer (score 0):

First, delete all this:

```
searchBar?.tintColor = UIColor.clear
            searchBar?.barTintColor = UIColor.clear
            searchBar?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            searchBar?.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
            searchBar?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
            searchBar?.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
            searchBar?.backgroundImage = UIImage()
```

Go to the Storyboard and change Bar Tint to your background color.
[image: http://imgur.com/a/YrJbX]

Comment: They were both set to `Clear Color`.  I changed them to a different color, but no avail.

Comment: @user1107173 See my edit. Delete all the inline changes you've done

Comment: Sorry, still no luck.